# Display content from custom wp_editor page in WooCommerce product pages

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to accomplish an `echo` on the WooCommerce product pages but I do not know how. I've created the custom submenu option (Products -> Hooked Content) and I've inserted the `wp_editor` on that page and given it a `Save` button. The content is saved, but I do not know how to display that content on the product page.

Any help is appreciated. Here's the code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_psm_meta', 5 );
function display_psm_meta() {
    // echo the content from the wp_editor here
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'hooked_content_page', 9999 );
function hooked_content_page() {
    add_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=product', 'Hooked Content', 'Hooked Content', 'edit_products', 'hooked_content', 'hooked_content_page_callback', 9999 );
}

function hooked_content_page_callback() {
    if ( isset( $_POST['psm_content'] ) ) {
        update_option( 'psm_content', $_POST['psm_content'] );
    } ?>
    <div class='wrap'>
        <h2>Hooked Content</h2>
        <form method='post'> <?php
            $content = get_option( 'psm_content' );
            wp_editor( $content, 'psm_content', $settings = array( 'textarea_rows' => '10' ) );
            submit_button( 'Save', 'primary' ); ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Appreciate all the help I can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function, to display your custom option content:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_psm_meta', 5 );
function display_psm_meta() {
    echo get_option( 'psm_content' );
}
```

Comment: thanks, that works. I know this is a new question, but why does it not accept saving pictures? I can insert a picture but when saving it, it just shows as `\"\"`

Comment: Please make a new question and add also php and wordpress as tags. I'm not sure why. Maybe other people know this.

Answer (score 0):

```
function custom_menu_page() 
{
    add_menu_page(
        'Email Scheduler Page',
        'Email Scheduler',
        'manage_options',
        'custom_email_slug',
        'custom_menu_callback',
        null,
        80
    );

    add_submenu_page(
        'custom_email_slug',          
        'Child Menu Page',            
        'Child Menu',                 
        'manage_options',             
        'custom_child_menu_slug',     
        'custom_child_menu_callback'  
    );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'custom_menu_page');

function custom_child_menu_callback() 
{
    echo '<div class="wrap"><h2>Child Menu Page Content</h2><br><br>';

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST" && isset($_POST['custom_child_menu_email'])) 
    {    
        // Validate and sanitize the entered email
        $entered_email = sanitize_email($_POST['custom_child_menu_email']);
        
        if (is_email($entered_email)) 
        {
            // Save the entered email
            update_option('custom_child_menu_email', $entered_email);
            echo '<div class="updated"><p>Saved email updated successfully!</p></div>';
            
            // Get the saved content
            $content = get_option('custom_menu_content');

            // Send email with the saved content
            $subject = 'Saved Content';
            $message = 'Here is the saved content: ' . PHP_EOL . $content;
            $headers = 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8';
            
            wp_mail($entered_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
            echo '<div class="updated"><p>Email sent successfully!</p></div>';            
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo '<div class="error"><p>Invalid email address. Please enter a valid email.</p></div>';
        }
    }
    
    $saved_email = '';
    
    echo '<form method="post" action="">';
    echo '<label for="custom_child_menu_email">Enter Email: </label>';
    echo '<input type="email" id="custom_child_menu_email" name="custom_child_menu_email" value="' . esc_attr($saved_email) . '" />';
    submit_button('Send Email');
    echo '</form>';

    echo '</div>';
}


function custom_menu_callback() 
{
    echo '<div class="wrap"><h2>Custom Email Scheduler Content</h2>';

    handle_custom_menu_form_submission();

    $content = get_option('custom_menu_content');
    
    // display_saved_content($content);
    
    display_editor($content);

    echo '</div>';
}

function handle_custom_menu_form_submission() 
{
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST" && isset($_POST['custom_menu_content'])) 
    {
        update_option('custom_menu_content', wp_kses_post($_POST['custom_menu_content']));
        echo '<div class="updated"><p>Saved content updated successfully!</p></div>';
    }
}

// function display_saved_content($content) 
// {
//     echo '<div><strong>Saved Content:</strong></div>';
//     echo '<div>' . wp_kses_post($content) . '</div>';
// }

function display_editor($content) 
{
    echo '<form method="post" action="">';

    wp_editor($content, 'custom_menu_editor', array(
        'textarea_name' => 'custom_menu_content',
    ));

    settings_fields('custom_menu_settings');
    submit_button('Save Changes');
    echo '</form>';
}

function custom_menu_register_settings() 
{
    register_setting('custom_menu_settings', 'custom_menu_content', 'custom_sanitize_textarea_field');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'custom_menu_register_settings');

function custom_sanitize_textarea_field($input) 
{
    return wp_kses_post($input);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).